# how to open simple "__.py" file as a module in python interpreter

Tags: python, python-module

I try to open simple file with"_.py" extencion as a module in interpreter and it returns me an error .
[image: stdin standard input]
how to set path variable in  win10 for automatic loading files as modules in Python 3.10 ?

help to resolve please!

I'm  trying to open file myfile1.py with path " C:\Users\lenat\Desktop\Python\Primeri " as standard Python module.
It is  possible to open this  file from integrated powershell ?

Comment: You can't specify a path in an `import` statement.  You have to add the path to the Python path (for example, `sys.path.append(...)` and then `import script11`.  In general, it's a bad idea to put absolute paths in your Python code, because some day you will want to run that on different computers

Comment: It  seems that  I need open file in "Python.exe " as module  with  its own path every  time ,  when I  want  to  open  it ?

Comment: No.  If you want to run "script11.py" from a command line, you do that from the command shell, not from inside Python.  If you are at a command prompt, and you do `cd Desktop\Python\Primeri`, then you can just type `script11.py`.  The Windows installer sets things up so that will start the script for you.